# laravel npm run watch does not compile Sass file into CSS

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project where I'm trying to compile Sass into CSS using npm run watch, but I'm getting the following error in terminal log: [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.entry['/js/app'] should not contain the item 'D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\epood5\resources\js\app.js' twice.
  -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 2
  npm ERR! epood4@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
  npm ERR! Exit status 2
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the epood4@1.0.0 development script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-04T15_18_53_974Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! epood4@1.0.0 watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the epood4@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-04T15_18_54_007Z-debug.log

RESOURCES/JS/APP.JS

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('alpinejs');
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.11",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
    },
    "name": "epood4",
    "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></a></p>",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "webpack.mix.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "tests"
    },
    "dependencies": [],
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a recent version of Laravel Mix which is good, however, you haven't updated the "scripts." I would still need to see webpack.mix.js. For now, you can update your package.json to the following and look harder into your app.js and webpack.mix.js.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.8.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.18",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.2.13",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.3",
        "sass": "^1.32.12",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
    }
}
```